# Как выполнить несколько функций по таймеру при изменении размера окна?

Tags: jquery

Для выполнения одной функции через 500 мс после изменения размера окна использую код:

```
$(window).resize( function() {
    clearTimeout(ProductsSliderTimeout);
    ProductsSliderTimeout = setTimeout(ProductsSliderInit, 500);
});
```

Как выполнить не одну, а сразу несколько функций?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Например, так:

```
$(window).resize( function() {
    clearTimeout(ProductsSliderTimeout);
    ProductsSliderTimeout = setTimeout(function(){
        function1();
        function2();
    }, 500);
});
```